# How to add a title to a drop down menu in Flutter Web?

Tags: flutter, web, dart

I'm currently working with Flutter web and I'm trying to achieve the following:

[DropdownMenu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fY3fn.png)

I can't set a title for the dropdown menu, only add the title as an item in the list.

I tried what Firas Krifa proposed and I got the following result:

[Result in small web size](https://i.stack.imgur.com/61Nu4.png)

[Result in 4K size](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9ooi4.png)

[Normal web size(FULL HD)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dHgc3.png)

I don't know why in the small size the dropdownmenu appears at the left of the dropdownbutton and the 4k size appears at the right.
Also on the normal size it appears on the title, while what I want is that it drops right under the title.

Comment: Add some code..

Answer (score 0):

The widgets  `DropdownButtonHideUnderline`   and `Theme` will help control how the dropdown looks in the title of the `AppBar`

https://material.io/guidelines/layout/structure.html#structure-app-bar

```
new AppBar(
  title: new Theme(
      child: new DropdownButtonHideUnderline(
      child: new DropdownButton<String>(
        value: _value,
        items: <DropdownMenuItem<String>>[
          new DropdownMenuItem(
            child: new Text('My Page'),
            value: 'one',
          ),
        ], 
        onChanged: (String value) {
          setState(() => _value = value);
        },
      ),
    ), 
    data: new ThemeData.dark(),
  ),
),
```

Comment: Thank you for answering but unfortunatly it only keeps the title, but the dropdownmenu doesn't drop where it should drop.

Comment: There are two non-required options that you'll most likely use. First is value, which stores the current value. If the value matches a DropdownMenuItem's value, the option item will be displayed as a selected item. It can be used to set the initial value as well. The other option is a hint, which is a widget that will be shown if no value selected.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
new DropdownButton<String>(
  items: <String>['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'].map((String value) {
    return new DropdownMenuItem<String>(
      value: value,
      child: new Text(value),
    );
  }).toList(),
  onChanged: (_) {},
)
```